# Overriding ModelChoiceField with HiddenInput doesn't work

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

I have form which generates from model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    company_id = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.all(),
                                            widget=HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user')
```

But it's doesn't work, and company_id is stay visible select field.
How I can create hidden field with company id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fieldnames between model and form should match. Use company in stead of company_id and it'll work.